# Converting dp into pixels for multiple screen support

Tags: android, screen, dpi

I am having a hard time to make this right.

Basically I am creating an ImageView and applying a LayoutParameter to it.

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(width, height);
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

I know that `width` and `height` parameters receive pixel numbers, so I am passing them in DP and converting it to absolute pixels using:

```
public int convertToPixels(float dpSize){
    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return ((int) (dpSize * density + 0.5f));
}
```

As far I know, this should make a drawable fill exactly the same area in different screens, right? Unfortunately, that is not happening at all.

Is there something wrong with these methods I am using?

These two emulators below have the same image and the same amount of DP.
Left emulator is 1.0 density and right one is 2.0. Why still does it look
so different ? Don't undertand..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
public class Convert{

    public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp){
        DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
        float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
        return Math.round(px);
    }
}
```

Just use it in a static way:

```
float requiredPixel = Convert.convertDpToPixel(16.0);
```

For more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Saini, take a look at my edit..   why it does not look right even with the same dp amount ?

Comment: it AM sure that the calculation is correct but the images are still different in termos of size